# I've ran into really weird error some templates in production doesn't load

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, deployment, django-templates

I deployed a django app on AWS EC2 every page is working but the login page and detail view page returning a 'template not found error while both of the views working on my machine.how can i fix this ? i already see it has to do something with my virtual machine.

to keep in mind here's my folder structure :

```
/Eyelizer
    /app1
    /app2    
    /Eyelizer
    /eyelizerenv
    /etc
```

I use this folder structure as it has something to do with the nginx and gunicorn configuration.

[image: the login template error]

Comment: can you add settings.py file here

Comment: If you think it has to do with your nginx and gunicorn configuration, please include those files as well.

Comment: before copying that from PuTTy , I can't see how they're related i mean it's these 2 templates that causes these problems only.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Unix systems are case sensitive. my files in the directory was `Login.html` and `patient_detail.html` while calling them in my `.py` files was different as `login.html` so by renaming the files it worked.